# "Cast" BluetoothSerial to HardwareSerial

Tags: serial, bluetooth

I have a function that accept an `HardwareSerial` class as argument:

```
void ProcessLine(HardwareSerial *serial, char *line)
{
    // do something
    serial->write("blablabla");
}
```

In my code I also have a `BluetoothSerial` that shares the required functions (i.e. `write()`) with `HardwareSerial`.

To avoid to duplicate the code of my `ProcessLine()` that is quite long, is there a way to "cast" a `BlutoothSerial` to a `HardwareSerial`?

Comment: `Stream` is the common base class https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/78719/can-you-use-serial-port-as-a-variable/78725#78725

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't "cast" between them. Instead you make use of *polymorphism*.

In the Arduino framework most classes fit into a "tree" with similar classes "hanging off" a common parent "branch".  In this case both `BluetoothSerial` and `HardwareSerial`, being both serial classes, are both children of the `Stream` class.  Indeed it is this `Stream` class (which itself is a child of the `Print` class) which gives these objects most of their functions.

So unless you *need* access to some function that is specific to the `HardwareSerial` class (such as the `.begin(...)` function) you should always work up the tree to the class that provides the most restrictive set of functions that suit your needs. In this case, since you are only printing data, it would be the `Print` class.  If you were reading data you would choose the `Stream` class.

So if you change your function to accept `Print *serial` instead of `HardwareSerial *serial` then it will accept *any* object that ultimately inherits from the `Print` object - so any serial objects, any network stream objects, etc.