# How to pass Strem object to my class

Tags: c++, class, stream

I'm trying to creaper class wraper to use an `Stream`object but I've an error when I try to compile.
My `.h`file :

```
#include <Arduino.h>

class TestSerialListener {
public:
  TestSerialListener(Stream &serial);
  void testPrint(void);
private:
  bool _listener_start;
  Stream &_serial;

  void startListener(void);

};
```

my `cpp`file

```
#include "TestSerialListener.h"
#include <Arduino.h>

TestSerialListener::TestSerialListener(Stream &serial) : _serial(serial)
{
}


void TestSerialListener::testPrint(){
    _serial.begin(115200);      <---------- error compilation 
    _serial.println("test");
}


void TestSerialListener::startListener(void)
{
    if(!_listener_start){
        _listener_start = true;
    }
}
```

And when i try to compile it I got this error : `error: 'class Stream' has no member named 'begin'`Why I can't use `begin()`in my classe ?

Comment: The compiler said: “you can't because the `Stream` class has no method named `begin`”. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Ok but why I can do `SerialUSB.begin(115200)`in my sketch ? @EdgarBonet

Comment: Because, `SerialUSB` does have a method named `begin`. **Some** `Stream`-derived classes can have such a method, It's just not something you can expect from **any** `Stream` object.

Comment: see https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/78719/can-you-use-serial-port-as-a-variable/78725#78725

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `begin()` method is defined in the `HardwareSerial` class, not in `Stream`. You can look that up yourself in your Arduino installation. For me these files are placed under `~/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.6/cores/arduino/` and are named `Stream.h` and `HardwareSerial.h`.

And if you  think about it, this is quite logical. The `Stream` class can represent any object, that can stream data. It doesn't know anything about how exactly the data is streamed on a hardware level. It just provides the convenient functions for handling the data. The `HardwareSerial` class then derives from `Stream` to get those data handling methods and adds its own methods to handle the hardware side of the problem, including setting a baudrate.

When providing a `Stream` reference to a class constructor you want to `begin()` the corresponding object outside of the class, before you start to stream any data through it. Doing it this way makes your class widely usable, since you could use any `Stream` object, even a file on an SD card.

So move the `begin()` line from your class to the `setup()` function in your main code.

---

For reference: Juraj showed the inheritance between the classes in his answer to [this question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/78719/can-you-use-serial-port-as-a-variable/78725#78725). Have a look at it, since it is quite enlightening.